# CORS Error while downloading the fonts from the Azure CDN using Sitecore PaaS

Tags: azure, paas, cdn

We have configured the Azure CDN for Sitecore Web Apps website, everything is working fine except the Fonts rendering from CDN, and we are getting below error:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: I have added the code for the pipeline. Please accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve the CORS CDN error , You would need to create a pipeline which adds the below request headers.This pipeline was written for Cloudfront on Amazon AWS instance , but the underlying logic is to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers to Sitecore requests.

```
public class CDNResponseHeaders : HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Execute(args.HttpContext.Response, args.HttpContext.Request);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                CustomLogger.LogError("An error occured processing the response headers.", e);
            }
        }

        public void Execute(HttpResponseBase response, HttpRequestBase request)
        {
            var dbContext = Sitecore.Context.Database;
            if (dbContext != null)
            {
                var configItem = dbContext.GetItem(Constants.CdnConfigurationMap);               
                var corsList = new List<string>();                
                if (configItem != null)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(configItem.Fields["Data"].Value))
                    {
                        corsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(configItem.Fields["Data"].Value);
                        if (corsList != null)
                        {
                            var clientOrigin = request.Headers.GetValues("Origin") ?? request.Headers.GetValues("origin");
                            if (clientOrigin != null)
                            {
                                string origin = clientOrigin[0];
                                CustomLogger.Info("Print Origin Value " + origin);

                                int myIndex = corsList.IndexOf(origin);
                                if (myIndex != -1)
                                {
                                    CustomLogger.Info("Request Origin Found add the CORS Header..." + clientOrigin);                                    
                                    //response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
                                    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "API, CRUNCHIFYGET, GET, POST, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS");
                                    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Origin, accept, app_key, authorization");
                                    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    CustomLogger.Info("Request Origin Unknown unable to add the CORS Header...");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

We also created a Sitecore Item which stores the domain names as Key/Value pairs for the whitelisting.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following rewrite rule to your web.config to add the required header on font files. The benefit of this is that you don't need any extra code - IIS rewrite module is available by default on Azure WebApps.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Enable CORS for Fonts">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access_Control_Allow_Origin" pattern=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^[^\?]+\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)(\?.*)?$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" value="*" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```